# What if I don't want my keyboard occupy 2/3 of the screen?

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I am sure fans like even this, but what if I don't like web page look like this

[image]

Is there any way to make keyboard widget smaller?

Comment: turn the device vertically

Answer (score 2):

The split keyboard takes up significantly less space. You may need to enable it in

```
Settings->General->Keyboards->Split Keyboard
```

To split, pull the left and right side of the keyboard apart with two fingers, or tap and hold the keyboard button in the bottom right then choose "split"...

[image: split menu screenshot]

You can also move the keyboard by grabbing the same button and dragging it up and down the screen.

[image: screenshot with split keyboard]

Comment: You can also split the keyboard by pulling it apart with your fingers. Makes it easier to use too, once you get used to it.

Answer (score 1):

The other option is use a bluetooth keyboard. Literally any bluetooth keyboard will work with any iOS device, and when that keyboard is active and connected, no on screen keyboard will be present, so you'll get the entire screen used for contents.

Or like other suggestions:
-Vertical mode uses less real estate
-Splitting the keyboard uses even less real estate

But what do I know, I'm a "fan"

Answer (score 0):

Nope; currently that's not possible even with the latest version of iOS.

Comment: I wonder if there is a 3rd party keyboard that takes up less space? Not sure as I don't use them but possibly worth a try. RedEagle2000 is correct IOS does not allow for size/position adjustments of the on screen keyboard.